# Position WinJSControl.UI.Flyout

Tags: javascript, css, winjs, flyout

How to position the flyout just above the button, when the browser is resized ?
The application has a button, which on click shows a flyout (WinJS flyout). But when the browser is resized the flyout doesnot always appear to be above the button.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that one of the elements was scaled. WinJS dowsnot consider the scaling factor while calculating the offset for the flyout. The solution was to pass a fake div (height, width as zero), and calculate the offset on it, which will later be used as an anchor for the flyout.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. It would be good to file this as an issue on https://github.com/winjs/winjs/issues as it doesn't look like it's logged yet.

Comment: Will file it soon. I have another issue with WinJS flyout, the flyout (element.wincontrol.hide()) operation takes a little more than expected time to close the flyout. Because of that two flyouts appear to be overlapped for a few seconds. Do you know if there is an existing issue or any similar for this ?

Comment: Just search the issues for "flyout" and you can check. That is: https://github.com/winjs/winjs/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+flyout. A quick glance doesn't show something like that but I didn't read them all.